# jQuery animate on class with many objects

Tags: jquery

I have about 1000 rows in a table, each looking like

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner_left">Name 1</div>
  <div class="inner_right">Value 1</div>
</div>
```

Now, I would like to move the right column by a jQuery animation as

```
$(".inner_right").animate({left:'50px'});
```

**Problem:** This takes quite some processor time to run.

So my question is:

**Question:** Is there a smarter way of doing that without having 1000 div's moving individually?

I could, of course, fill the table by first filling the first column and then the second, each in an enclosing div (to then only animate one of those). But (since there is more stuff attached to the filling row-by-row procedure) I would prefer another solution. Something like overlapping div's, where a value div is both a child of a row div and of a column div.

Comment: Use CSS3 to animate many elements. But anyway, moving 1000 divs simultaneously seems weird in all case

Comment: This might be a good idea, thanks. I will look into that (though at a first glance, it seems to be difficult to get it run nicely across browsers).

Comment: Older browsers don't support CSS3 animation. But like said before, better would be to not animate so many elements. I guess you could try a workaround and animate only visivle elements (on viewport) and set for other directly left property. Providing a jsfiddle would help you in order to get more accurate answers

Comment: It is indeed not likely that all rows are visible at the same time, so I could as well only do the animation on the visible entries (which is more likely to be <200).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best idea is to change your HTML from:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner_left">Name 1</div>
  <div class="inner_right">Value 1</div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner_left">Name 2</div>
  <div class="inner_right">Value 2</div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner_left">Name 3</div>
  <div class="inner_right">Value 3</div>
</div>
```

To:

```
<div class="outer_left">
  <div class="inner_left">Name 1</div>
  <div class="inner_left">Name 2</div>
  <div class="inner_left">Name 3</div>
</div>

<div class="outer_right">
  <div class="inner_right">Value 1</div>
  <div class="inner_right">Value 2</div>
  <div class="inner_right">Value 3</div>
</div>
```

And then move div .outer_right

Comment: problem is its table row content, you still need for each row a DIV outer_right

Comment: as I was writing, I'd prefer to not fill the table col by col for other reasons (not explicitly given), so I was first looking for another solution. But thx anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to include another library on your page, you might want to consider Greensock's TweenMax.

http://api.greensock.com/js/

Have a look at the staggerTo() method, where you can pass in a jQuery selector, and it will stagger all of your rows.  I've found that it's quite a bit faster at animating than jQuery.

Benchmark information: http://www.greensock.com/jquery/

Pseudo code for you would be something like this:

```
// link to the library
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
// the function
<script>
    function staggerRows(){
        TweenMax.staggerTo($(".inner_right"), 0.2, {left:"50px"}, 0.1);
    }
</script>
```